# Чем отличается __repr__ от __str__?

Tags: python, faq, python-faq

Возьмем как пример парочку выдуманных классов:

```
import requests

class A:
    def __init__(self, a="string", b=10, c=["a", "b", "c", 1, 2, 3]):
        # параметр c - произвольной длины
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

class B:
    def __init__(self, A_object):
        # A_object - объект типа A
        self.neighbor = A_object
        self.session = requests.Session()
```

1) Как следовало бы написать `__repr__` и `__str__` для этих классов?

2) [Документация](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) говорит о том, что `__repr__` - это однозначное представление объекта в виде строки, которое можно использовать, чтобы воссоздать точно такой же объект, а если это невозможно, то вывести *какое-нибудь полезное сообщение*. Очень похоже, что требуется сериализовать объект таким образом. В чем же тогда отличие от связки `__getstate__`, `__setstate__`? Эти два метода тоже могут запросто строку вернуть и требования у этой строки такие же - однозначное представление объекта. Зачем же дублирование?

И наоборот, как замену getstate, setstate можно придумать следующее:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return "A({a}, {b}, {c})".format(a=self.a, b=self.b, c=self.c)
```

а потом вызывать это:

```
A1 = A()
A2 = eval(A1.__repr__())
```

3) Та же самая документация говорит, что `__str__` - должен вывести красивое, читабельное информационное сообщение, отражающее объект. Как тогда различить результат этого метода и *какое-нибудь полезное сообщение* из `__repr__`?

4) Далеко не всегда можно представить какой-то объект в виде строки. Например, функции, длинные коллекции, другие объекты без str и без repr. Выходит, что в этом случае либо не выполняется требование `__repr__`, либо необходимо для всех подобных объектов вывести содержание `__dict__`, что хранит значение всех-всех методов и переменных. Выглядит это решение плоховато, что же делать?

5) Возвращаясь к документации `__repr__` - можно пример ситуации, когда невозможно однозначно представить объект как строку? Объекты ведь не имеют к квантовому миру никакого отношения - они ВСЕГДА детерминированы, всегда есть набор переменных и набор методов. но не зря же в документации эта строка?

6) А еще есть `__format__`, который тоже должен возвращать строку...

Comment: Похожий вопрос: [Difference between `__str__` and `__repr__` in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1436703/4279)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`datetime.date` хорошо иллюстрирует разницу:

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> date.today() # sys.displayhook() uses repr() by default
datetime.date(2016, 6, 13)
>>> print(date.today()) # print uses str() here
2016-06-13
```

`repr(obj)` возвращает *однозначное* текстовое представление (representation) объекта полезное для отладки, сообщений об ошибках, REPL, которое (иногда) позволяет его (теоретически) восстановить: `eval(repr(obj)) == obj`.

`str(obj)` возвращает *читаемый* текст. Для многих объектов имеет смысл определить `__repr__()` (так как реализация по умолчанию в `object.__repr__` не слишком информативна). `__str__()` имеет смысл определять для объектов, для которых существует «естественное» человеко-читаемое (неспецифичное для Питона) представление (как в примере с датой), например, для логов.

Если `__str__` не определён, то `str()` использует `repr()`.

Разные форматы рассчитаны на разного потребителя (человек/программа, Питон/общее назначение). Вот график, иллюстрирующий когда разные форматы удобно использовать:

```
^ ^ 
| | Более дружелюбный для человека
|                            +---+
|                            |str|
|                            +---+
|
| +----+                    +----+
| |repr|                    |json|
| +----+                    +----+
|
| +------+
| |pickle|
| +------+
|
| | Машино-читаемый
+--------------------------------->

Специфичный для Питона -> Более общий
```

> 1) Как следовало бы написать `__repr__` и `__str__` для этих классов?

```
class A:
    def __repr__(self):
        return "A(%r, %r, %r)" % (self.a, self.b, self.c)

class B:
    def __repr__(self):
        return "<B(neighbor=%r), session=%r>" % (self.neighbor, self.session)
```

Объекты `B` не могут быть восстановлены из `repr()`.

> 2) Документация говорит о том, что `__repr__` - это однозначное представление объекта в виде строки, которое можно использовать, чтобы воссоздать точно такой же объект, а если это невозможно, то вывести какое-нибудь полезное сообщение. Очень похоже, что требуется сериализовать объект таким образом. В чем же тогда отличие от связки `__getstate__`, `__setstate__`? Эти два метода тоже могут запросто строку вернуть и требования у этой строки такие же - однозначное представление объекта. Зачем же дублирование?

`pickle` (`__getstate__/__setstate__`) не является человеко-читаемым форматом. Цели и ограничения на дизайн другие. То что `eval(repr(obj))` иногда работает, ещё не значит что это хорошая идея использовать это вместо `pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(obj))` или `json.loads(json.dumps(obj))`.

Основной потребитель `repr()` это человек. Потребитель `pickle.dumps()` это как правило программа, например, `multiprocessing` использует `pickle` для обмена данными между процессами.

> 3) Та же самая документация говорит, что `__str__` - должен вывести красивое, читабельное информационное сообщение, отражающее объект. Как тогда различить результат этого метода и какое-нибудь полезное сообщение из `__repr__`?

Если вы не видите имя типа, то это не `__repr__()` (за очевидным исключением констант (Python literals) таких как `'abc'`, `123`).

> 4) Далеко не всегда можно представить какой-то объект в виде строки. Например, функции, длинные коллекции, другие объекты без str и без repr. Выходит, что в этом случае либо не выполняется требование `__repr__`, либо необходимо для всех подобных объектов вывести содержание `__dict__`, что хранит значение всех-всех методов и переменных. Выглядит это решение плоховато, что же делать?

`eval(repr(obj))` это подсказка, а не требование: если объект большой, то очевидно нужно сократить его представление. Во многих случаях, можно использовать многоточие:

```
>>> numpy.arange(10000000)
array([      0,       1,       2, ..., 9999997, 9999998, 9999999])
>>> print(numpy.arange(10000000))
[      0       1       2 ..., 9999997 9999998 9999999]
```

Ещё раз: потребитель `repr()`—программист Питона, который видит это представление в REPL или debugger.

> 5) Возвращаясь к документации `__repr__` - можно пример ситуации, когда невозможно однозначно представить объект как строку? Объекты ведь не имеют к квантовому миру никакого отношения - они ВСЕГДА детерминированы, всегда есть набор переменных и набор методов. но не зря же в документации эта строка?

Документация говорит про случай, когда `eval(repr(obj)) == obj` не имеет смысла:

```
>>> object()
<object object at 0x7f9ff2c8c1d0>
```

> 6) А еще есть `__format__`, который тоже должен возвращать строку...

Этот специальный метод позволяет типу переопределить как `format()` себя ведёт, например:

```
>>> "{:%Y-%m-%d}".format(datetime.today())
'2016-06-13'
```

В Питоне 2 есть `__unicode__()` как `__str__()`, но `unicode` возвращает. А ещё [`__fspath__()` (PEP 519)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0519/) появился. Могут быть другие протоколы, которые возвращают строки (со своим обоснованием).