# Проблемы с переносом кода с java на python: глобальную переменную считает локальной

Tags: java, python, python-3.x

Здравствуйте.
Я пришёл из мира Java, и в процессе вынужденного переноса работающего кода (построение дерева из списка его предков) на python столкнулся c проблемой. Код на python возвращает пустое дерево:

```
parent1 = input().split()
parent =[]
constructed =[]

class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.data)


root = TreeNode(0)

def constructNode(i, constructed, parent):

    if constructed[int(i)] is not None:
        return

    if parent[int(i)] == -1:
        constructed[i] = TreeNode(i)
        root = constructed[i] 
        return

    pc = constructed[parent[i]]
    if pc is None:
        constructNode(parent[i], constructed, parent)

    constructed[i] = TreeNode(i)

    if pc is not None:

        if pc.left is None:

            pc.left = constructed[i]
        else:
            pc.right = constructed[i]


def constructTreeBottomUp(parent):
    n = len(parent)
    constructed = [TreeNode(0) for i in range(n)]
    for i in range(n):
        constructNode(i, constructed, parent)
    return root

def getInOrder(root):
    if root is None:
        return
    if root is not None:
        getInOrder(root.left)
        print(root.data + " ")
        getInOrder(root.right)


root1 = constructTreeBottomUp(parent1)
print("T1", root1)//returns T1 = 0
```

Проблема, видимо, в строке `root = constructed[i]`, где root считается локальной переменной в `constructNode()`, несморя на определение `root = TreeNode()` до этого.
Я пыталася фиксить `global root = TreeNode()`,`global root = TreeNode(0)`,
но python считает строку либо Py:EQ или вообще "undefined at module level".
Не мог бы кто-нибудб, пожалуйста, объяснить, как это в пайтоне фиксится?

***Код на Java, для сравнения:***

```
 private class TreeNode
{
    int data;
    TreeNode left;
    TreeNode right;

    TreeNode(int data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }
}

TreeNode root;

private void constructNode(int i, TreeNode[] constructed, int[] parent)
{
    // node already created for this index 'i'
    if (constructed[i] != null)
    {
        return;
    }
    if (parent[i] == -1)
    {
        constructed[i] = new TreeNode(i);
        root = constructed[i];
        return;
    }
    if (constructed[parent[i]] == null)
    {
        constructNode(parent[i], constructed, parent);
    }

    constructed[i] = new TreeNode(i);

    if (constructed[parent[i]] != null) 
    {
        if (constructed[parent[i]].left == null)
        {
            constructed[parent[i]].left = constructed[i];
        }
        else
        {
            constructed[parent[i]].right = constructed[i];
        }
    }
}

public TreeNode constructTreeBottomUp(int[] parent)
{
    TreeNode[] constructed = new TreeNode[parent.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < constructed.length; i++)
    {
        constructNode(i, constructed, parent);
    }
    return root;
}
public void getInorder(TreeNode root)
    {
        if (root == null) return;
        getInorder(root.left);
        System.out.println(root.data + ", ");
        getInorder(root.right);
    }
```

Comment: Приведите пример входных и выходных (что должно получиться) данных. Что значит "список предков" дерева?

Comment: @insolor, список предков-это, по сути, массив a[i], в котором индексы-дети, а a[i]-родители.
Массив родителей, например,[1 -1 1]. Индексы [0,1,2]. 1-корень, 0 и 2 -его дети. Так что дерево, в итоге, 0 1 2
И я хочу его именно вернуть поэтоапно по node'ам. Просто печать я уже сделал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем случае не нужны ни глобальные переменные, ни рекурсия. Просто создаем список узлов (причем, сразу с нужными значениями), проходим по списку родителей, привязываем каждый узел к соответствующему родителю.

В класс узла для удобства добавил метод добавления ребенка.

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, data, left=None, right=None):
        self.data = data
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def add_child(self, node):
        if not self.left:
            self.left = node
        elif not self.right:
            self.right = node
        else:
            raise ValueError('No free children links')

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'TreeNode({self.data!r}, {self.left!r}, {self.right!r})'.format(self=self)


def construct_tree(parents: list):
    # Сразу заполняем список узлами с соответствующими значениями:
    constructed = [TreeNode(i) for i in range(len(parents))]

    root = None  # Корень пока неизвестен
    for i, parent in enumerate(parents):
        # Если индекс родителя -1, значит это корень
        if parent == -1:
            root = constructed[i]
        else:
            # Подвязываем текущий узел соответствующему родителю
            # (отдельная функция construct_node() оказалась не нужна)
            constructed[parent].add_child(constructed[i])

    return root

# Пример использования:
print(construct_tree([-1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]))

# Вывод: TreeNode(0, TreeNode(1, TreeNode(3, None, None), TreeNode(4, None, None)), TreeNode(2, TreeNode(5, None, None), TreeNode(6, None, None)))
```

По поводу различий Python и Java:

1. Строке `TreeNode root;` примерно соответствует строка `root = None`, т.е. просто записываем в переменную пустое значение. Вызов `TreeNode(0)` здесь совершенно не нужен, получается что будет создан лишний объект, который будет перезаписан другим значением, после чего старое значение будет удалено сборщиком мусора. Просто лишняя работа для интерпретатора.
2. Для создания массива с пустыми значениями (`TreeNode[] constructed = new TreeNode[parent.length];`) можно использовать строку `constructed = [None for i in range(len(parent))]`. Python - язык с динамической типизацией, тип тут указывать не нужно (да и в общем-то негде), и тем более не нужно заполнять массив при помощи `TreeNode(0)`. В вашей первоначальной реализации получается, что массив уже заранее заполнен узлами, и условие `constructed[int(i)] is not None` в функции `construct_node()` будет истинно для любых `i`.
3. И все-таки о глобальных переменных. Если нужно из функции изменить значение глобальной переменной, то это делается так:

   ```
   root = None

   def constructNode(i, constructed, parent):
       global root
       ...
       if parent[int(i)] == -1:
           constructed[i] = TreeNode(i)
           root = constructed[i] 
           return
   ```
4. Ну и последнее, входные данные полностью подготавливать (в данном случае, приводить значения к целым числам) лучше заранее:

   ```
   parent1 = [int(item) for item in input().split()]
   ```

Comment: ого, как подробно, спасибо!
Можно тогда пару вопросов по написанному? 
1) Во-первых,  выдаётся  `def add_child(self, node: TreeNode):
NameError: name 'TreeNode' is not defined` 
У вас 3 питон?
2) В root = None получается, что у нас объект root какого типа?
А если нам надо, чтобы он был TreeNode()? При динамической типизации это не указывается, тут я понял. 
3) В _repr_(), я так понял, идёт что-то сродни toString()? !r - это что за зверь?
Отдельное спасибо за глобальные переменные, тут я голову себе после джавы сломал порядочно. :)

Comment: Да, действительно, выдает ошибку, убрал. Это аннотация типа (что-то типа пометки, какого типа предполагается аргумент, нужно или убрать, или взять в кавычки, т.к. на момент использования класс еще не определен). По поводу `root = None` - в Python опять же, динамическая типизация. На практике это означает, что у переменных нет типа, тип есть у значений, т.е. какое значение в переменную положим, такой тип и будет. Первоначально тип будет `NoneType`, потом уже, когда в переменную будет записана ссылка на узел, тип будет `TreeNode`.

Comment: всё, теперь понял, спасибо большое.
Пошёл читать про аннотациии.

Comment: Метод `__repr__` возвращает строковое представление объекта, но скорее не для пользователя (как `__str__`), а например для отладки. В идеале, строку, полученную из объекта при помощи функции `repr()` можно подставить в `eval()`, и будет получен объект полностью аналогичный исходному. Вот тут по поводу этого можно почитать: [**Чем отличается repr от str**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/534440/%d0%a7%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-repr-%d0%be%d1%82-str/534446#534446)

Comment: `'{!r}'` - это как раз форматирование через `repr()`, `'{!r}'.format(x)` аналогично `repr(x)`. В моем примере еще используется обращение к полям объекта прямо в строке форматирования, это уже в общем-то излишество)

Answer (score 1):

В питоне для присвоения значения глобальной переменной надо в начало фунции добавит `global varname`, тоесть в вашем случае `global root`.

Comment: `...иначе будет просто создана локальная для функции переменная`. А вообще глобальные переменные зло :)

Comment: @gt22, cпасибо, но здесь ещё вопрос, как в питоне определить, что это экземпляр класса. На global root в начале функции пишет AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'left', (что логично, не задано, что это экземпляр TreeNode()), а на попытки сделать  `global root /br
    root = TreeNode(0)` или `global root = TreeNode(0)' ругается.