# Массивы в ctypes для Python 3: Почему он не печатает мне двумерный массив, а печатает <__main__.c_char_p_Array_4 object at 0x...> строчку?

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, ctypes

У меня возникло несколько вопросов насчёт работы с двумерными массивами в C и, одновременно с этим, работа с этими массивами из Питона. На Си я начал прогать совсем недовно. Вот есть код на Си, который в идеале должен превращать строку в массив слов (надо просто для тренировки). Я попытался сделать его наиболее простым:

```
char **splitter (char *tos){
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int y = 0;
    static char words[100][100];
    while (tos[i]){
        if (tos[i] != ' '){
            words[j][y] = tos[i];
            y++;
        }
        else{
            y = 0;
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return words;
}
```

Дальше я обращаюсь к библиотеке с этой функцией из Питона

```
from ctypes import *
spll = CDLL('./splitter.dll')
s = "собака стреляет в охотника"
bs = s.encode("cp1251")
spli = spll.splitter
spli.argtypes = [c_char_p]
spli.restype = c_char_p * 4
n = spli(bs)
print(n)
```

Питон мне печатает вот что:

```
<__main__.c_char_p_Array_4 object at 0x03FED8A0>
```

Вопросы в следующем: 
1) Почему он не печатает мне двумерный массив, а печатает такую строчку?
2) Можно ли задать при помощи ctypes массив с произвольным числом элементов? То есть, как сделать так, чтобы я мог подать строку с произвольным количеством слов на вход.
3) Почему не работает

```
 static char *words[100];
```

вместо

```
 static char words[100][100];
```

?

С массивами символов ведь так можно

Простите, если вопросы слишком простые)

Answer (score 1):

`'<__main__.c_char_p_Array_4 object at 0x...>'` это результат по умолчанию для `__repr__` метода, вызываемого из `print()` здесь. В общем случае, задача `repr()` получить однозначное текстовое представление Питон объекта для отладки. См. [Чем отличается `__repr__` от `__str__`?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/534440/23044)

Так как реализация по умолчанию `__repr__` не очень полезна, можно самостоятельно отформатировать, к примеру, конвертировать ctypes массив C-строк (bytes) в список Питон-строк (Unicode):

```py
>>> import ctypes
>>> words = "собака стреляет в охотника".split()
>>> arr = (ctypes.c_char_p * len(words))(*map(str.encode, words))  # utf-8
>>> arr
<__main__.c_char_p_Array_4 object at 0x...>
>>> [*arr]
[b'\xd1\x81\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb1\xd0\xb0\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0',
 b'\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd1\x80\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8f\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82',
 b'\xd0\xb2',
 b'\xd0\xbe\xd1\x85\xd0\xbe\xd1\x82\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0']
>>> [*map(bytes.decode, arr)]
['собака', 'стреляет', 'в', 'охотника']
```

См. [Что значит * (звёздочка) и ** двойная звёздочка в Питоне?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/594651/23044)

Из C у вас указатель (`char**`) возвращается, который ctypes в коде в вопросе в `c_char_p * 4` тип превращает.

Чтобы произвольную длину вернуть, необходимо размер массива из функции вернуть:

```c
char** split(char* input_string, char** output_array_of_strings, int* psize);
```

где `split()` внутри присваивает `*psize = <кол-во строк в результате>;`

Вызвать из Питона, чтобы размер получить:

```py
size = ctypes.c_int()
pp = your_lib.split("abc".encode(), None, ctypes.byref(size))
```

Указатель можно в массив превратить:

```py
arr = ctypes.cast(pp, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char_p * size)).contents
```

См. [How to convert pointer to c array to python array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7543675/4279).