# Сериализация в Python. Почему так много модулей?

Tags: python, сериализация

Я мало знаком с сериализацией. Вот что я понял:
Есть пакеты, удобные для человека `json`, есть пакеты, удобные для хранения в Python - `pickle`. Есть межязыковые пакеты - `protobuf`.
Ну три модуля должно бы хватить?
Когда я открыл PyPi с поисковым вопросом 'serialization' - я получил 4+ страницы модулей. Например  `protobuf` имеет 3 модуля... 
Итак 2 вопроса.
1. Почему `dill` например, не совместили с `pickle`?
2. Можно ли обойтись 3-4 стандартами на все случаи жизни? Если нет - то какова причина такого разнообразия модулей?

Comment: связанный вопрос [Чем отличается `__repr__` от `__str__`?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/534440/23044) (на график посмотрите)

Comment: вообще вопрос из области: почему так много слов? Потому что много разных ситуаций в жизни бывает: no size fits all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По-моему нет смысла бороться с эволюцией и естественным отбором. Хорошие, удобные, эффективные, etc. модули вытеснят те, которые им проигрывают.

**Пример из моей рабочей жизни:**

около 2 лет назад я выбрал для себя, как мне тогда казалось, идеальный модуль -
 [HDF5 (PyTables)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37010212/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-upload-a-big-csv-file-in-notebook-to-work-with-python) для быстрой и удобной (де-)сериализации данных в [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/). Несколько позже появилась новая библиотека - [Feather Format (Apache Arrow)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/feather-format), которая значительно быстрее HDF5, но в ней отсутствуют такие например вещи как чтение с диска по индексу. Теперь в зависимости от задачи я выбираю либо HDF5 (если мне надо обрабатывать наборы данных, которые не помещаются в памяти) или Feather если мне надо быстро читать/писать полный набор данных (который помещается в памяти).

Вполне возможно, что в будущем в Feather Format добавят доступ по индексу или появится другая еще более крутая библиотека и я с удовольствием перейду на неё.

Сейчас я изучаю [Apache Spark](https://spark.apache.org/) и там точно такая же ситуация - единого стандарта нет и постоянно появляется что-то новое. Некоторые из этих новых форматов выживают и вытесняют устоявшиеся "стандартные" форматы, другие же новые форматы просто вымирают...

Если бы был один незыблемый формат, то не было бы никакого развития и усовершенствования.

Answer (score 5):

Потому, что модули пишет и публикует на PyPI не одна какая-то организация, а множество независимых программистов со всего мира. Каждый из них имеет своё видение какой-либо области, включая сериализацию. Когда какой-то модуль с PyPI кажется мне неудобным или не полностью реализует мои потребности, я пишу свой и публикую.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: то есть 100 000 + модулей PyPi никто не модерирует? Ну, это ж не гитхаб все же... какое то одобрение "старейшин" должно происходить или нет...

Comment: Более того, там есть множество давно устаревших модулей, которые невозможно запустить в современном окружении. И есть не меньше  модулей, которые были сломаны изначально. И есть модули абсолютно бессмысленные. Такая ситуация во всех публичных репозиториях для всех общеупотребительных языков.

Comment: Жаль, не могу поставить отметку "ответ" на оба ответа.
Они дополняют друг друга....