# Python выводит не то, что я ожидал

Tags: python, вывод

Итак, начну с кода:

```
>>> class CountFromBy:
>>>   pass

>>> a = CountFromBy()
>>> a
<__main__.CountFromBy object at 0x0000025F135BD630>
```

А теперь вопрос: что это такое ↑ ? По идее должно вывести "0", но выводит это. Прежде, чем кидать в меня помидоры, объясните пожалуйста, почему так происходит и как это исправить?

Вот почему я считаю, что должно быть "0"[image: скрин из книги "Изучаем программирование на Python"]

И ещё один интересный момент: если написать

```
>>> a.increase()
```

В выводе отобразиться следующее:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    a.increase()
AttributeError: 'CountFromBy' object has no attribute 'increase'
```

Comment: Вы инициализировали переменную объектом. Для вашего объекта не задано, как он будет выглядеть при преобразовании к строке (для вывода на экран). Поэтому просто пишется, что это такой-то объект, расположенный по такому-то адресу в памяти. Откуда должен появиться 0 совершенно не понятно.

Comment: А расскажите, почему вы решили, что должен быть 0?

Comment: Обновил вопрос, думаю теперь ясно, почему я считаю, что должно быть "0"

Comment: Там справа написано что класс еще не создан...

Comment: @JackPorfavore, из текста "посмотрим, что класс должен делать (когда мы напишем код)" - т.е. это запланированное поведение, а не фактическое.

Comment: @insolor Возможно. Но на протяжении всей книги я всё повторял за автором(то есть писал код в IDLE в точности как и в книге) и в итоге я получал тот же результат, что и автор. Другими словами запланированное поведение перетекало в фактическое и на практике всё работало. Кроме этого случая. И потом, код в итоге выполняется, но вместо ожидаемого(мною) "0" выходит "<__main__.CountFromBy object at 0x0000025F135BD630>" И, помимо первой проблемы, почему не работает метод increase?

Comment: @JackPorfavore "почему не работает метод increase?" - по той же причине, он еще не написан.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такой пустой класс:

```
class CountFromBy:
    pass
```

Ничего не делает. При выводе объекта класса просто выводится, что это объект такого-то класса, объявленного в таком-то модуле, и что он расположен по такому адресу:

```
<__main__.CountFromBy object at 0x0000025F135BD630>
```

Ожидать, что пустой класс будет выполнять какие-то полезные функции - это все равно что от пустого ящика ожидать, что он будет работать как телевизор: что-то показывать, и каналы будут переключаться.

Чтобы объект класса работал как описано в книге, нужно инициализировать начальное значение, заменить метод `__repr__` (или `__str__`) по-умолчанию (какой из них переопределять в данному случае не важно, но на будущее почитайте ответы к вопросу [**Чем отличается `__repr__` от `__str__`?**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/534440/1365)), определить метод `increase`.

Пример класса с требуемым поведением:

```
class CountFromBy:
    def __init__(self, from_=0, by=1):
        self.value = from_
        self.by = by

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)

    def increase(self):
        self.value += self.by
```

`from_` с подчеркиванием, т.к. `from` - это ключевое слово, его нельзя использовать в качестве идентификатора.

Comment: Все бы ничего, но `from` :D

Comment: @ПавелДурманов, спасибо, поправил

Comment: Спасибо, @insolor это действительно похоже на то, что я искал. Половину правда не понимаю, но это поправимо!