# В чем разница между %r и %s в Python?

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-2.7

Объясните, пожалуйста, в чем разница между ними. Я лишь знаю, что %r выводит "сырое" значение. Но можете показать на примере, что он делает?

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Чем отличается `__repr__` от `__str__`?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/534440/%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-repr-%D0%BE%D1%82-str)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете прочитать о различиях [тут](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) и [здесь](https://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex6.html). Основной посыл таков:

- `%r` использует функцию `repr` для встроенных типов включает в себя кавычки и все специальные символы экранируются
- `%s` использует функцию `str` (симметрично `%r`)

Пример:

```
s = "spam"
print(repr(s))
# 'spam'
print(str(s))
# spam
```

Иными словами, `%s` красиво форматирует объект (делает beautify). Чуть более сложный пример для кастомных типов:

```
import datetime
d = datetime.date.today()
print(str(d))
# '2011-05-14'
print(repr(d))
# 'datetime.date(2011, 5, 14)'
```