# Class Counter append-remove

Tags: python, counter

Нужно реализовать класс, добавляющий и удаляющий из объекта типа Counter элементы:
Я написала код и не могу понять, почему ответ выдает типа :<**main**.MyCounter at 0x1b9a5b8bb50>

```
from collections import deque 
    class MyCounter:
        def __init__(self, iterable):
            self._data = None
            self._iterable=deque(iterable)
        def append(self, item):
            self.item=item
            self._iterable.append (self.item)
        def remove(self, item):
            self._iterable.remove (self.item)
        
    c = MyCounter('sdfghfddfsrfbgd')
    c.append ('b')
    c.remove ('c')
    c
```

Comment: вы обращаетесь к объекту для вывода, а надо к его свойству c._iterable

Answer (score 1):

Чтоб объект вывести в консоль или файл, его нужно преобразовать в строку. И это то, как по умолчанию работает такое преобразование - печатает имя класса и уникальный идентификатор объекта (что-то типа адрес в памяти).

Чтоб печаталось что-то более осмысленное определите метод `__repr__` в классе:

```
class MyCounter:
    ... тут все как раньше
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"MyCounter[data={self._data}, iterable=${self._iterable}]"
```

Есть еще один метод `__str__`, который используется для преобразования в строку в некоторых случаях, и его тоже обычно имеет смысл переопределять. [Тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/534440/%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-repr-%D0%BE%D1%82-str) смотрите в чем разница и когда какой используется.